# how to make rabbitmq keep data after server restart?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

after following 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html
I declared my queue as:

```
//first true is for durable so it should survive restart
channel.queueDeclare(queName, true, false, false, null);
```

the way I write to queue is as follows (if it makes difference):

```
channel.basicPublish("", queName, null, string.getBytes());
```

but if I restart the server all  data gets deleted.

how can I declare a queue in rabbitMQ that will keep the data if server gets restarted?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was stupid mistake

I changed :

```
channel.basicPublish("", queName, null, string.getBytes());
```

to :

```
channel.basicPublish("", queName, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, string.getBytes());
```

now it works as expected.